# "column specified more than once" during CREATE TABLE AS SELECT

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a shapefile containing multipolygons and a raster file. What I want is to extract the count, median, mean, min and max of the pixels which intersect with the corresponding polygons and aggregate the values row-wise

For that I'm using the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE <some_table_name> AS
SELECT ply.*,
       (St_SummaryStats(St_Union(ST_Clip(rast,1,geom, true)))).*
FROM  <shapefile_name> AS ply 
     ,<raster_filename>
WHERE st_intersects(rast,geom)
GROUP BY gid;
```

But while doing so, I am getting this error:

```
ERROR:  column "count" specified more than once
SQL state: 42701
```

Also, if I remove the initial query of creating table, I'm getting output like this:

[image: Output Table]

There is a repetition of the count, min, max and other stats columns.

I want to get rid of these repetitive columns and I also want to create the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that both `ply` and the function `st_summarystats` have a column called `count`, so the new table would have two columns with the same name, which is not possible.

You have to use different column names. The easiest way would be to specify the column names explicitly:

```
CREATE TABLE some_table (colname1, colname2, ...)
AS SELECT ...
```

To get rid of the columns you don't want, specify the columns you need instead of `*`.